# Shifting points in shapefile based on velocity and direction in raster layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, point

I have a point shapefile and I need to shift each point based on the velocity and direction of the raster cell of a corresponding shapefile. I cannot seem to find a tool in ArcGIS Pro that would easily solve this problem. The only workaround I have thought of is calculating the x and y coordinate of each point and then performing a field calculation on those values.

Comment: Add supporting screenshots for better understanding.

Comment: Clarification question - what do you mean by "the raster cell of a corresponding shapefile"? Shapefiles are a vector format (i.e. point, line, polygon) whereas rasters are gridded storage of data.

Comment: What I meant was that I have a series of points in a region that will have moved over time. In order to estimate their new position I have a velocity raster and a directional raster that cover the extent of the study area. Is there a way to shift the point locations (or create a new point file with shifted locations) using the velocity and directional information in the rasters?

Comment: convert your rasters to points. then spatial join them back to your points. in terms of shifting them based on the direction in the attribute table, I'm not sure how you could do that